# Can't connect to Ubuntu VM on VirtualBox

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I've just updated W11 to 22H2 and my VM is not working properly anymore. Tried to connect to it through Putty and Solar-Putty but they return this:

> Network error: Connection timed out

I don't know if it's related to the Windows update, but here is some info:

- Running Ubuntu 22.04 on Oracle VirtualBox
- The VM **has internet access** (pinging google.com returns all packets)
- Network adapter is "NAT"
- `hostname -I` used to return **class B address** (192.168....) and
  now it returns **class A address** (10.0...)
- /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml output:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

Any tips would be welcome! Thanks

Comment: You can try setting up port forwarding in VirtualBox, or you can set the NIC from NAT to Bridged so that it is on the same network as the host and will become part of your actual network.

Comment: Switching to Bridget did the trick. Thank you!